# Cast changing generic type

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
    public class Grid<T>
    {
        public int Width { get; }
        public int Height { get; }
        public float CellSize { get; }
        public Vector2 GridOffset { get; }
        public T[,] GridObjects { get; }

        public Grid(int width, int height, float cellSize, Vector3 gridOffset, Func<Grid<T>, int, int, T> createGridObjectMethod)
        {
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
            this.CellSize = cellSize;
            this.GridOffset = gridOffset;

            GridObjects = new T[width, height];

            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    GridObjects[x, y] = createGridObjectMethod(this, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public interface IPathNode
    {
        PathNode GetPathNode();
    }
```

```
    public class PathNode : IPathNode
    {
        private readonly Grid<IPathNode> grid; 
        public int X { get; }
        public int Y { get; }

        public PathNode PreviousNode;

        public PathNode(Grid<IPathNode> grid, int x, int y)
        {
            this.grid = grid;
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to create a Grid instance with the following line:

```
            grid = new Grid<PathNode>(10, 10, 1, new Vector3(-5, -5, 0), (g, x, y) =>
            {
                Grid<IPathNode> test = (Grid<IPathNode>)g;
                return new PathNode(g, x, y);
            });
```

The problem is that PathNode asks for a Grid and my grid is made of PathNodes (or any other type that implements that interface).

How can I cast it, or instantiate it?

Tried casting the grid object, but it will fail to compile.
Also adding generics to the PathNode class but I don't like that

Comment: Even though `PathNode` inherits from `IPathNode`, it doesn't mean that `Grid<PathNode>` inherits from `Grid<IPathNode>`. They are two distinct types.

Comment: I don't think you want your interface method to return a concrete class.  GetPathNode should return and IPathnode

Comment: Here's why it can't work. Say you have an `IFruit` interface and you have implemented `Apple` and `Banana` to implement the interface. Then if you declare a `List<Apple>` and if you could cast it to `List<IFruit>` then you'd be allowed to add a `Banana` to a list that can only take `Apple`. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok that makes a lot more sense thanks. And what should be the correct approach?

Comment: @Axvemi - If your grid can take any type of `IPathNode` then declare it as `new Grid<IPathNode>` instead of `new Grid<PathNode>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah but the grid will be in my case Grid<Node> where node does have the PathNode, since it will implements the interface, and more other data not related with the pathnode

Comment: @Axvemi - Based on your code I'm not sure I understand that last comment. Can you please expound?

Comment: @Enigmativity My real use case, I have a class called Node that also implements the interface, and the Grid is instantiated like Grid<Node>. Then Node has a PathNode reference. Since I cant change the grid type, I added what I commented on the solution below. Added generics to the PathNode class and the interface, even if its just for it to work

Comment: @Axvemi - I really still don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a restriction to the PathNode and the interface (and adding generics to it). I had to edit some of the code but it works. Don't really like this option since I only use the generics for it to work but yeah.

```
public class PathNode<T> : IPathNode<T> where T : IPathNode<T>
public interface IPathNode<T> where T : IPathNode<T>
```

Comment: Ah, the old [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: I don't think you need that though. Just `PathNode<T> where T:IPathNode { .... Grid<T> grid; ... }`